# Instant messaging on android?

Tags: android, chat, messaging

I need to implement Instant messaging functionality in my Android application but 
I have no idea how to do this. Is there any open source API avilable for chat or is 
there any other Instant messenger(chat) functionality in Android?

Comment: It looks like you are a beginner. Making such an application that lets two different devices communicate is rather complicated

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search reveals a Google Code application, which you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/), project simple-android-instant-messaging-application. It looks like it gives you all of the code to create a database, Registration, authentication, friends, notifications, and simple chat.

You can likely look over this code, and implement some of it into your current application.

If you like, there is a demo of this app [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/downloads/detail?name=simple_android_im_application_demo.avi&can=2&q=).

I hope it helps!

Comment: I saw this code. And This code have errors which I can't fix. But I do exactly like in documentation.

Comment: Have you set up a local webserver to test it with, as said [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/#How_to_make_it_run), and then set up the database on the same server to test it with, using the supplied sql code?

Comment: Also, do you have the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) plugin to compile with?